# Convert to dataframe from JSON in R

Tags: json, r

I am facing issues with conversion of JSON to dataframe. I tried using libraries: `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO`,`rjson`.

I keep getting 'invalid character in the string'  or unclosed string.

I am getting this data from a standard API so should be able to parse this json. Also, JSON editors can parse this data just fine.

My question is:

Is there a standard way using which I can make sure that my dataframe gets created and ignore above errors?

My best guess was to convert this data to JSON format using `toJSON` function from either of the libraries but if I use

```
   newdata <-  fromJSON(toJSON(data))
```

it somehow never gets converted to dataframe. Why is that?

If I instead use

```
  newdata <- fromJSON(data)
```

I get a valid dataframe but sometimes because of above errors, it doesn't work which is what I am trying to know. How do you deal with this?

I have tried using this too  freshDeskTicketsToDF <-

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(readLines(textConnection(freshDeskTickets)), collapse=""))
```

1. It seemed to solve the problem but somewhere I got unclosed string with this method which I otherwise did not.

Are there better ways to deal with this in R?

2. Also, why is it that using toJSON on data passed to fromJSON never gets converted to a dataframe?
3. If I decide to take off html tags from the values assisgned to keys in JSON data. How does that work? Can I do that?

Edit: It looks like I get this error when I have `<html tags>` in my "string data" but I have them all across my JSON data and I don't get it every time.

How to deal with problems like this?

Note: this issue not specific to the data that I have. What I am looking for is ways to deal with problems like these and not one specific solution to a single problem.

2. I just realized thattoJSON converts R objects to JSON and not JSON to valid JSON. Is there a way to do it instead?

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fwd_emails": [

    ],
    "reply_cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fr_escalated": false,
    "spam": false,
    "email_config_id": 1000062780,
    "group_id": 1000179078,
    "priority": 1,
    "requester_id": 1022205968,
    "responder_id": 1018353725,
    "source": 1,
    "company_id": null,
    "status": 5,
    "subject": "Order number-100403891",
    "to_emails": [
      "contact@stalkbuylove.com"
    ],
    "product_id": null,
    "id": 174093,
    "type": "Order Status query",
    "due_by": "2016-09-02T08:57:30Z",
    "fr_due_by": "2016-09-02T02:57:30Z",
    "is_escalated": true,
    "description": "<div dir=\"ltr\">Hi Team,<div><br></div>\n<div>I have ordered an item from your website, order number-100403891. I had called on August 30 2016 to postpone the delivery date. The guy i spoke from your end had confirmed that he will hold and push the delivery date to September 5 or 6 or 7 2016. And he confirmed the same.</div>\n<div>However, the guy I spoke to<b> did not do it</b>. </div>\n<div>I got to know it from ABHINAV from your customer care team who I spoke to on August 1st at 13:10. Hence I have put a request again and he said he will talk to some guys and give me the desired dates for delivery which is 5,6,7 of September 2016. </div>\n<div>Please let me know the concern on this and hope for a quick turn around.</div>\n<div><br></div>\n<div>Thank you,</div>\n<div>Hari,</div>\n<div>+91-9538199699.</div>\n</div>\n",
    "description_text": "Hi Team,\r\n\r\nI have ordered an item from your website, order number-100403891. I had\r\ncalled on August 30 2016 to postpone the delivery date. The guy i spoke\r\nfrom your end had confirmed that he will hold and push the delivery date to\r\nSeptember 5 or 6 or 7 2016. And he confirmed the same.\r\nHowever, the guy I spoke to* did not do it*.\r\nI got to know it from ABHINAV from your customer care team who I spoke to\r\non August 1st at 13:10. Hence I have put a request again and he said he\r\nwill talk to some guys and give me the desired dates for delivery which is\r\n5,6,7 of September 2016.\r\nPlease let me know the concern on this and hope for a quick turn around.\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\nHari,\r\n+91-9538199699.\n",
    "custom_fields": {

    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-01T07:51:18Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-11T11:00:33Z"
  },
  {
    "cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fwd_emails": [

    ],
    "reply_cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fr_escalated": false,
    "spam": false,
    "email_config_id": 1000062780,
    "group_id": 1000179078,
    "priority": 1,
    "requester_id": 1022148025,
    "responder_id": 1021145209,
    "source": 1,
    "company_id": null,
    "status": 5,
    "subject": "Defect in d piece",
    "to_emails": [
      "contact@stalkbuylove.com"
    ],
    "product_id": null,
    "id": 174092,
    "type": "Return",
    "due_by": "2016-09-01T15:51:00Z",
    "fr_due_by": "2016-09-01T09:51:00Z",
    "is_escalated": false,
    "description": "<div><br></div>\n<div><br></div>\n<div><br></div>\n<div><div style=\"font-size:75%;color:#575757\">Sent from Samsung Mobile</div></div>",
    "description_text": "\n\n\nSent from Samsung Mobile",
    "custom_fields": {

    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-01T07:51:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-06T09:00:14Z"
  },
  {
    "cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fwd_emails": [

    ],
    "reply_cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fr_escalated": false,
    "spam": false,
    "email_config_id": 1000062780,
    "group_id": 1000179078,
    "priority": 1,
    "requester_id": 1022205895,
    "responder_id": 1018353725,
    "source": 1,
    "company_id": null,
    "status": 5,
    "subject": "Re: StalkBuyLove Return Request for order: 100404435",
    "to_emails": [
      "StalkBuyLove <contact@stalkbuylove.com>"
    ],
    "product_id": null,
    "id": 174088,
    "type": "Refund query",
    "due_by": "2016-09-01T15:43:56Z",
    "fr_due_by": "2016-09-01T09:43:56Z",
    "is_escalated": true,
    "description": "<div>Hi. Can u deposit the amount if i giv u my account number. Right away i cant choose any other product frim ur site. <br><br>Sent from my iPhone</div>\n<div>\n<br>On Sep 1, 2016, at 12:38 PM, StalkBuyLove &lt;<a href=\"mailto:contact@stalkbuylove.com\" rel=\"noreferrer\">contact@stalkbuylove.com</a>&gt; wrote:<br><br>\n</div>\n<blockquote><div>\n<div><img title=\"StalkBuyLove\" alt=\"Stalkbuylove\" src=\"http://www.stalkbuylove.com/launcher_icons/Newlogo_Stalkbuylove_240x50.png\"></div>\n<div>Hello <b>Anamica Aggarwal</b>,</div>\n<div>We have initiated a return request for order: <b>100404435</b> with the following products:</div>\n<table style=\"width:80%\">\r\n                                <tbody>\n<tr style=\"background-color:#B0C4DE\">\r\n                                   <th>Item Name</th>\r\n                                   <th>Sku</th>\r\n                                </tr>\n<tr>\r\n                                        <td style=\"text-align:center\">Articuno Top</td>\r\n                                        <td style=\"text-align:center\">IN1627MTOTOPPCH-198-18</td>\r\n                                   </tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>\n<div>Lots of love,</div>\n<div>Team SBL</div>\n<img src=\"http://mandrillapp.com/track/open.php?u=30069003&amp;id=bff0a5daee4a47fe9c6b04d2680c3c39\" height=\"1\" width=\"1\">\r\n</div></blockquote>",
    "description_text": "Hi. Can u deposit the amount if i giv u my account number. Right away i cant choose any other product frim ur site. \n\nSent from my iPhone\n\n> On Sep 1, 2016, at 12:38 PM, StalkBuyLove <contact@stalkbuylove.com> wrote:\n> \n> \n> Hello Anamica Aggarwal,\n> \n> We have initiated a return request for order: 100404435 with the following products:\n> \n> Item Name\tSku\n> Articuno Top\tIN1627MTOTOPPCH-198-18\n> Lots of love,\n> \n> Team SBL\n> \n",
    "custom_fields": {

    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-01T07:43:56Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-11T11:00:32Z"
  },
  {
    "cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fwd_emails": [

    ],
    "reply_cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fr_escalated": false,
    "spam": false,
    "email_config_id": 1000062780,
    "group_id": 1000179078,
    "priority": 1,
    "requester_id": 1022205881,
    "responder_id": 1021145209,
    "source": 1,
    "company_id": null,
    "status": 5,
    "subject": "Details for order",
    "to_emails": [
      "contact@stalkbuylove.com"
    ],
    "product_id": null,
    "id": 174086,
    "type": "Order Status query",
    "due_by": "2016-09-01T15:42:50Z",
    "fr_due_by": "2016-09-01T09:42:50Z",
    "is_escalated": false,
    "description": "<div><span></span></div>\n<div>\n<span>Hey can i get details of my order </span><br><span>How much more time will it take to get delivered? </span><br><span>Order no-</span><h2 style=\"font-weight: normal; margin: 0px;\"><font><span style=\"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\">100403837</span></font></h2>\n<span></span><br><span>Sent from my iPhone</span><br>\n</div>",
    "description_text": "Hey can i get details of my order \r\nHow much more time will it take to get delivered? \r\nOrder no-\r\n100403837\r\n\r\nSent from my iPhone\n",
    "custom_fields": {

    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-01T07:42:50Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-06T09:00:13Z"
  },
  {
    "cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fwd_emails": [

    ],
    "reply_cc_emails": [

    ],
    "fr_escalated": true,
    "spam": false,
    "email_config_id": 1000062780,
    "group_id": 1000179078,
    "priority": 1,
    "requester_id": 1022204690,
    "responder_id": 1021145209,
    "source": 1,
    "company_id": null,
    "status": 5,
    "subject": "Refund",
    "to_emails": [
      "contact@stalkbuylove.com"
    ],
    "product_id": null,
    "id": 174080,
    "type": "Refund query",
    "due_by": "2016-09-01T15:36:26Z",
    "fr_due_by": "2016-09-01T09:36:26Z",
    "is_escalated": true,
    "description": "<div>\r<br>Bank statement as asked for refund! Please intiate the proccedings asap!<br>\n</div>",
    "description_text": "\r\nBank statement as asked for refund! Please intiate the proccedings asap!\n",
    "custom_fields": {

    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-01T07:36:26Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-07T08:00:19Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Despite your pleas, you're still going to need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's a part of [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO; others need to be able to reproduce the issue with sample data.

Comment: @alistaire: Updated

Comment: Much better. It looks like there's a bunch of HTML in there that's causing the issue. You could hack it out with regex and deal with it separately, but if there's any way to parse it without regex, that's preferable.

Comment: That's what I feel too. Shouldn't have to take it off. But how?

Comment: It looks like `RJSONIO::fromJSON` does better than `jsonlite::fromJSON`, though the former keeps the nested list instead of coercing to data.frame. You can do that after the fact, though. `purrr` may be helpful for arranging the list as you like.

Comment: @alistaire: True but with RJSONIO , I get unclosed string error

Answer (score 2):

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- stream_in(file("~/data/sample.json"))
```

This `stream_in` function directly convert into datafram

Comment: It seemed to be working pretty smooth until I got : Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       [{"cc_emails":[],"fwd_emails":[
                     (right here) ------^ . How do I deal with this?

Comment: its because column names varies across the json files.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a closing `]` on one of the lines. You can do something like: `which(lapply(readLines('mydata.json'), function(x) tryCatch({jsonlite::fromJSON(x); 1}, error=function(e) 0)) == 0)` to see which lines throw errors, then inspect those lines in your .json file.